# How I can find the missing number in digit with php

Tags: php

I have a number like 914027, and now I want to find the missing numbers in the 6 digits eg: 3,5,6,8 are missing in that number. I have 300 numbers so it is not easy to find, that's why I want to do it with code

```
$str = '914027';
$one=$str[0];
$two=$str[1];
$three=$str[2];
$four=$str[3];
$five=$str[4];
$six=$str[5];
```

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/strpos ?

Comment: Do you mean you want each number as it's own variable?

Comment: And what have you tried? [Edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
$str = '914027';
if ($missNumbers = array_diff(range('0','9'), str_split($str))) {
    echo sprintf("Missing: %s", implode(', ', $missNumbers));
}
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/HelUL

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions for this.

Set an array with all the digits:

```
$digits = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
```

Now split the number to an array:

```
$str = "914027";
$numDigits = str_split($str);
```

Now you can use array_diff to find the difference between them:

```
$missing = array_diff($digits, $numDigits);
```

The result will be an array with the missin digits:

```
["3","5","6","8"]
```

If you have a lot of numbers, put them all in an array, and loop through it.

Comment: Leggendario's answer is exactly the same, but more neat.

Comment: @JohnCartwright No it's not. Place this code in a script and test it your self before voting down with no reason.

Comment: @Chibani True, but by the way the question was asked, I believe that the user that asked that is a novice, so I "split" the code to pieces.

Comment: This only works with the range 0-9, because you are splitting every single character. For example, the number 12 is split into a 1-2. 12 is a VALID number. I thought about my answer before replying to you. And no, I'm not going to test everyone's code when I can clearly see theres an error in logic.

Comment: @JohnCartwright And that what he wanted - to find the missing digits, not numbers! Read the question again. Pay attention to his example.

Comment: I guess you guys are better mind readers than I am. I interpreted the  (poorly) written question differently.

Comment: @JohnCartwright True, the question is poorly written, but he gave the number 914027, and "3,5,6,8 is missing" - and that is exactly the missing digits. That's all...

Comment: @RonDadon Fair enough. I would remove my downvote if I could (you need to edit your post since it's now locked).